# Convert javascript function to c function for loadrunner scripting

Tags: javascript, client, correlation, loadrunner

Below is a javascript function to generate a code at client side.
The code generated by this function is then compared with the user entered code and if it matches, the request is passed to the server.
I am doing scripting in Load Runner, where either I need to correlate this dynamically generated code at client side (which is probably not possible, since it is not returned by server), or I should convert the javascript function to c-function and implement in load runner script.

Please help.

```
function DrawCaptcha()
{
    var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)+ '';
    var b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)+ '';       
    var c = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)+ '';  
    var d = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)+ '';  
    var e = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)+ '';  
    var f = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)+ '';  
    var g = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)+ '';  
    var code = a + ' ' + b + ' ' + ' ' + c + ' ' + d + ' ' + e + ' '+ f + ' ' + g;
    document.getElementById("txtCaptcha").value = code;
    document.form1.txtInput.value="";
}

function ValidCaptcha()
{
    var str1 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtCaptcha').value);
    var str2 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtInput').value);
   if (str1 != str2) 
    {
    alert("Captcha Does Not Match");
    document.form1.txtInput.focus();
    DrawCaptcha();
    return false;
    } 

}

function removeSpaces(string)
{
    return string.split(' ').join('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reproduce the code in LoadRunner (if Necessary).   Since this is a client-side captcha and not a server-side captcha you may have to do nothing since the value is not received from nor passed to the server and all it serves is to be a local gatekeeper before the next request is made.

As you have already recorded the next request, which would be the result of a positive captcha then you may have to do nothing except run the script again, not withstanding any other non-captcha dynamic data which needs to be in place to execute the next page.

Comment: What do you mean by " not withstanding any other non-captcha dynamic data which needs to be in place to execute the next page"? I can not proceed with next request unless the captcha value is validated. How can, reproducing code in LR, help here?

Comment: If your captcha is generated 100% locally on the client and authenticated locally and does not involve a server based authentication before moving on then you likely do not even need to include the code because you have already captured the affirmative test case from a successful captcha with your next set of requests.   You likely only need to ensure that an appropriate amount of think time is in place for people completing the captcha (see http://www.google.com/recaptcha as an example of a server based mechanism)